# Java 8 stream API to convert List to TreeMap

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, collectors

Hi i am trying to convert the following code using java 8 stream API.

```
private Point3d findClosestNodeToParentStartNode1(List<Point3d> points,Point3d parentStartVertex)
    {
        
        TreeMap<Double, Point3d> distanceMap = new TreeMap<Double, Point3d>();
        for (Point3d point : points) {
            distanceMap.put(parentStartVertex.distanceTo(point), point);
        }
        return distanceMap.firstEntry().getValue();
    }
```

I am trying to do something like

```
Map<Double, Point3d> result =  points.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(parentStartVertex.distanceTo(point->point) , point -> point));
TreeMap<Double, Point3d> distanceMap = new TreeMap<>(result);
return distanceMap.firstEntry().getValue();
```

Comment: Using TreeMap for the purpose of finding the closest point is quite inefficient. Just keep track of the smallest known distance and discard points further away than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't even compile as the key function is wrong. You also have an intermediate step which isn't needed, you can directly use the `toMap` function which takes 4 arguments and return a `TreeMap` directly.

Something like this should work

```java
TreeMap <Double, Point3d> distanceMap = points.stream().collect(
Collectors.toMap(
  parentStartVertex::distanceTo,
  Function.identity(),
  (k1, k2) -> k2,
  TreeMap::new));
return distanceMap.firstEntry().getValue();
```

For what is worth I don't think there is anything wrong with the `forEach` approach and in this case it might even be easier to read (and might even be faster due to less overhead).

```java
TreeMap<Double, Point3d> distanceMap = new TreeMap<Double, Point3d>();
points.forEach( point -> distanceMap.put(parentStartVertex.distanceTo(point), point));
return distanceMap.firstEntry().getValue();
```

Comment: Worked! I should have been used forEach to make it more simpler. :)

Comment: You don’t even need the `TreeMap` when you only want the minimum element, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74259755/2711488) demonstrates.

Comment: True but that wasn't the question (although we could argue that the forEach wasn't either).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the smallest distance (`min`) between the target `parentStartVertex` and the individual points in the list, then you can use `Stream#min` or `Collections#min` with a custom `Comparator` comparing based on the distance between `parentStartVertex` and the individual items. Pick one of the solutions below:

```
/**
 * Returns null in case the list `points` is empty
 */
private Point3d findClosestNodeToParentStartNode1(List<Point3d> points, Point3d parentStartVertex) {
        return points.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(parentStartVertex::distanceTo))
                .orElse(null);
}
```

```
/**
 * Throws NoSuchElementException in case the list `points` is empty
 */
private Point3d findClosestNodeToParentStartNode1(List<Point3d> points, Point3d parentStartVertex) {
        return Collections.min(
                points,
                Comparator.comparingDouble(parentStartVertex::distanceTo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the solution is not correct as explained in the comment, still by reading the implementation of toMap() with two arguments in the source code the solution becomes rather obvious with a few minor adjustments.

The default Map Implementation the function will use is HashMap, you just need to provide the map implementation you need as last argument like:

```
 Map<Double, Point3d> result =  points.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(parentStartVertex.distanceTo(point->point) , point -> point, Treemap::new));
```

If you chek out the source code you'll see that the toMap method you used just calls the overload method beneath it with the defaul HashMap implementation:

```
    /**
     * Returns a {@code Collector} that accumulates elements into a
     * {@code Map} whose keys and values are the result of applying the provided
     * mapping functions to the input elements.
     *
     * <p>If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to
     * {@link Object#equals(Object)}), an {@code IllegalStateException} is
     * thrown when the collection operation is performed.  If the mapped keys
     * may have duplicates, use {@link #toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)}
     * instead.
     *
     * @apiNote
     * It is common for either the key or the value to be the input elements.
     * In this case, the utility method
     * {@link java.util.function.Function#identity()} may be helpful.
     * For example, the following produces a {@code Map} mapping
     * students to their grade point average:
     * <pre>{@code
     *     Map<Student, Double> studentToGPA
     *         students.stream().collect(toMap(Functions.identity(),
     *                                         student -> computeGPA(student)));
     * }</pre>
     * And the following produces a {@code Map} mapping a unique identifier to
     * students:
     * <pre>{@code
     *     Map<String, Student> studentIdToStudent
     *         students.stream().collect(toMap(Student::getId,
     *                                         Functions.identity());
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @implNote
     * The returned {@code Collector} is not concurrent.  For parallel stream
     * pipelines, the {@code combiner} function operates by merging the keys
     * from one map into another, which can be an expensive operation.  If it is
     * not required that results are inserted into the {@code Map} in encounter
     * order, using {@link #toConcurrentMap(Function, Function)}
     * may offer better parallel performance.
     *
     * @param <T> the type of the input elements
     * @param <K> the output type of the key mapping function
     * @param <U> the output type of the value mapping function
     * @param keyMapper a mapping function to produce keys
     * @param valueMapper a mapping function to produce values
     * @return a {@code Collector} which collects elements into a {@code Map}
     * whose keys and values are the result of applying mapping functions to
     * the input elements
     *
     * @see #toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)
     * @see #toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator, Supplier)
     * @see #toConcurrentMap(Function, Function)
     */
    public static <T, K, U>
    Collector<T, ?, Map<K,U>> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                    Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper) {
        return toMap(keyMapper, valueMapper, throwingMerger(), HashMap::new);
    }
```

```
    /**
     * Returns a {@code Collector} that accumulates elements into a
     * {@code Map} whose keys and values are the result of applying the provided
     * mapping functions to the input elements.
     *
     * <p>If the mapped
     * keys contains duplicates (according to {@link Object#equals(Object)}),
     * the value mapping function is applied to each equal element, and the
     * results are merged using the provided merging function.  The {@code Map}
     * is created by a provided supplier function.
     *
     * @implNote
     * The returned {@code Collector} is not concurrent.  For parallel stream
     * pipelines, the {@code combiner} function operates by merging the keys
     * from one map into another, which can be an expensive operation.  If it is
     * not required that results are merged into the {@code Map} in encounter
     * order, using {@link #toConcurrentMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator, Supplier)}
     * may offer better parallel performance.
     *
     * @param <T> the type of the input elements
     * @param <K> the output type of the key mapping function
     * @param <U> the output type of the value mapping function
     * @param <M> the type of the resulting {@code Map}
     * @param keyMapper a mapping function to produce keys
     * @param valueMapper a mapping function to produce values
     * @param mergeFunction a merge function, used to resolve collisions between
     *                      values associated with the same key, as supplied
     *                      to {@link Map#merge(Object, Object, BiFunction)}
     * @param mapSupplier a function which returns a new, empty {@code Map} into
     *                    which the results will be inserted
     * @return a {@code Collector} which collects elements into a {@code Map}
     * whose keys are the result of applying a key mapping function to the input
     * elements, and whose values are the result of applying a value mapping
     * function to all input elements equal to the key and combining them
     * using the merge function
     *
     * @see #toMap(Function, Function)
     * @see #toMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator)
     * @see #toConcurrentMap(Function, Function, BinaryOperator, Supplier)
     */
    public static <T, K, U, M extends Map<K, U>>
    Collector<T, ?, M> toMap(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyMapper,
                                Function<? super T, ? extends U> valueMapper,
                                BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                                Supplier<M> mapSupplier) {
        BiConsumer<M, T> accumulator
                = (map, element) -> map.merge(keyMapper.apply(element),
                                              valueMapper.apply(element), mergeFunction);
        return new CollectorImpl<>(mapSupplier, accumulator, mapMerger(mergeFunction), CH_ID);
    }
```

Comment: This won't work as you need an additional function to resolve conflicts as well. Nor does the function to generate the key work.

Comment: @Teddy Tsai distanceTo also gives compilation error :(

Comment: Yeah thanks for noticing, since it's mapping by distance it could have duplicate keys, a merger is needed to resolve the conflict and there is no method that takes 3 arguments and a default merger, even so the default throwing merger probably would not work.

But you can still take the track to follow from the answer, by just reading the source code of the toMap() method the solution becomes pretty clear

Comment: So you haven't (fully) answered the question, but gave another puzzler for the reader to solve :).